# How to shorten multiple classes with the same code implementation

Tags: swift, protocols, swift-protocols

For example I have these 5 TVC's whose names are `OneTVC, TwoTVC, ..., FiveTVC` and all of the has implemented a protocol called `SomeProtocol`

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var sourceViewController: UIViewController! { get set }
    weak var bottomView: SomeCustomView! { get set }

    func configure(sourceViewController sourceViewController: UIViewController)
}
```

all TVC's have implemented SomeProtocol with the same codes

```
class OneTVC: UITableViewCell, SomeProtocol {
    var sourceViewController:UIViewController!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomView: SomeCustomView!

    func configure(sourceViewController sourceViewController: UIViewController) {
        self.sourceViewController = sourceViewController

        bottomView.btnOne.addTarget(.... #selector(self.doSomething(_:)))
        bottomView.addTarget(.... #selector(self.doAnother(_:)))
    }
}

/* all these codes */
extension OneTVC {
    func doSomething(sender:UIButton) {
        // same codes as TwoTVC ..., FiveTVC
    }

    func doAnother(sender:UIButton) {
        // same codes as TwoTVC ..., FiveTVC
    }
}
/* all these codes */
```

What I want to be able to do is not write codes that are enclosed in `/* all these codes */`

Using protocols I may be able to do something like this

```
protocol SomeProtocol {
    var sourceViewController: UIViewController! { get set }
    weak var bottomView: SomeCustomView! { get set }

    func configure(sourceViewController sourceViewController: UIViewController)
}

extension SomeProtocol {
    func doSomething(sender:UIButton) {
        // some custom implementation
    }

    func doAnother(sender:UIButton) {
        // some custom implementation
    }
}
```

But I can't do this cause this protocol needs to be declared as an Objective-C protocol like so `@objc protocol SomeProtocol` because of `addTarget(_:, _:, _:)` but by doing this I can't use these optional or implicit operators `! or ?` for declaring Variables inside the protocol

If I create a superclass I can't override variables that I need to be @IBOutlets for example.

```
class SomeSuperClass: UITableViewCell, SomeProtocol {
    var sourceViewController:UIViewController!
    @IBOutlet weak var bottomView: SomeCustomView!

    func configure(sourceViewController sourceViewController: UIViewController) {
        self.sourceViewController = sourceViewController

        bottomView.btnOne.addTarget(.... #selector(self.doSomething(_:)))
        bottomView.addTarget(.... #selector(self.doAnother(_:)))
    }
}

class OneTVC: SomeSuperClass  {
    @IBOutlet override weak var bottomView: SomeCustomView! // < this here makes an error
    // .. rest of the codes
}
```

What do I do?

Comment: How about creating a super class for your cells, and implementing the common code there?

Comment: do just want a single handler for all your TVCs?

Comment: wait I'll add an edit regarding @almas comment

Comment: @ChristianAbella Something like that. I just don't want to rewrite/re-copy paste all code if I need to change one functionality.

Comment: you can always use the tag property of UIView to store a unique value (id) that will help you identify each cell.  That way you can just write one handler  and if there are special conditions, you can use the tag.

Comment: oh the view.viewWithTag(Int) as! SomeUIObjectHere

I'll try that

Comment: Thanks It worked.